# Accessing variables outside of a class and function

Tags: php, class, variables

I am trying to get the value of a function inside of a class.

classes.php

```
 class luresClass {

  public function lureSelect() {

   global $lureChoice;
    if ($_POST['airtemp'] == 2 && $_POST['watertemp'] == 5) { 
          $lureChoice = 1;
         }
    else {$lureChoice = 0;}

 }   

}
```

This is the main file (index.php) that needs to access the value of $lurechoice.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

    $displayLureChoice = new luresClass(); 
    $displayLureChoice->lureSelect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl."lure WHERE id = ".$lureChoice."");    
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          echo "Lure Choice: ".$row['type']. "<br />Color: " .$row['color']. "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

The user chooses certain items from a form and it is to return the if/else values.

I have tried making $lurechoice a global variable within the function lureSelect() in the classes.php file but doesn't work. I tried making it a public var in the class but that failed as well.

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use globals you simply set the variable in your class and then use a function pass it back:

**Class**

```
class luresClass {

    public $lureChoice;

    public function lureSelect() {

        if ($_POST['airtemp'] == 2 && $_POST['watertemp'] == 5) {

            $this->lureChoice = 1;
        }
        else {
            $this->lureChoice = 0;
        }
    }  

    public function getLureChoice(){
        return $this->lureChoice;
    } 

}
```

**Code**

```
$displayLureChoice = new luresClass(); 
$displayLureChoice->lureSelect();

$lureChoice = $displayLureChoice->getLureChoice();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl."lure WHERE id = ".$lureChoice."");    
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "Lure Choice: ".$row['type']. "<br />Color: " .$row['color']. "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Ahh, it was the function that returns the value that I didnt get. I learn by picking apart the code. This answer works.